# Decouple collections from Model

Tags: php, laravel

Suppose I have collections **c1**, **c2** and **c3** in my **Model**.

I use it as `Model::c1()`.

How can I decouple these collections from my **Model** to a separated class but still be able to do `Model::c1()`?

Comment: do you mean you have relationships c1, c2, c3 ?

Comment: No, they are custom methods.